# How to check if class attribute contains something?

Tags: c#, xpath, webdriver

I have two buttons, back and next:

```
   By.XPath("/html/body/div/div[3]/main/div/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/nav/div/button[1]")

   By.XPath("/html/body/div/div[3]/main/div/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/nav/div/button[2]")
```

First goes to previous page, second goes to the next page of my list. When I open my page, first button will be disabled until I get to another page or both will be disabled if my list is short or emty. I need to click those buttons if they are not disabled. Only diference between disabled and not is class attribute:

```
class="disabled btn btn-plain btn-default-hover"
class="btn btn-plain btn-default-hover"
```

So how can I check if buttons class atribute contains 'disabled'? scenario goes like this - if second button active click 'next' and then if first button active click 'back'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//el is the web element
if(el.getAttribute("class").split(" ").contains("disabled"))
{  
    //your code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two buttons with the ids "button1" and "button2"..

You can check with something like this:

```
if(document.getElementById("button1").className.indexOf("disabled") > 1) {
  // what to do if disabled...
} else {
  // what to do if active...
}
```

And of course, you can do the same for the other button...

Comment: Wow... embarassing....
I'm used to answering javascript questions I guess I didn't notice where I was clicking.  :)

Answer (score 0):

by using jquery write the following code

```
var ClassAtttr = $("#YourElementId").attr("class");

 if (ClassAtttr.indexOf('Your Expression'))
 {
   //do somthing
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the '.Enabled'

```
WebElement backButton = driver.FindElement('Your Locator');
if(backButton.Enabled)
{
  'Your action to be performed
}
```